# How can I extend a public wifi (for one or multiple devices) without physical access to the router

Tags: wifi, repeater, bridge

How can I extend a public Wi-Fi signal (e.g., eduroam, citywifi) in another room, for one or multiple devices? I do not have physical access to the public wifi router.

Some of the wifi have web authentication and others use usn/pwd.

Can this be done? Which devices do I need and how can I set them up?

I am reading confusing/controversial posts and I would like to have an opinion from the community here.

For now, I have tried a repeater. However, this seems that it can not work. I guess I need to set the public wifi's router as well to connect with the repeater, which I do not have access to.

I have seen some hints and tips for a two-device solution, a bridge (to receive the signal), an ethernet connection to a router, and the wifi router to create the internal wifi network.

What do you think?

Any help is very welcome

Comment: You can watch this video and go forward you will definitely get an idea. https://youtu.be/31MLIMevgZQ

Answer (score 0):

To extend the range of the Wi-Fi, you'll need some networking equipment like Repeaters or APs. This is correct.
These network equipment require to be associated or paired with each other via Wireless Protected Setup (WPS) or Device Provisioning Protocol (DPP) like methods for data flow.
Given methods, unfortunately, require physical access to the main router to apply actions :

- WPS button usage for pairing,
- No-touch configuration with DPP.

When thinking on it a little more; if would it be possible, an infinitive ranged network might be easily created within multi-hops. Think on it. Good luck.

Comment: No need of external repeater just buy another router and use that as a signal extender. following this video https://youtu.be/31MLIMevgZQ